# Getting the largest date value for each record

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I have a layer in QGIS that has four date fields - date1, date2, date3, date4. Using pyqgis I wish to find the latest date (ignoring null values) for every record from these four columns and copy that value into a field called MaxDate.

If the four date fields are null, then MaxDate is set at the value of last_date

It feels like there should be an easy solution, but I have yet to crack it!

The fields are all 'QDate' format (yyyy-MM-dd)

[image: Data Example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a PyQGIS solution. It assumes that you have already all the fields created with the same names you mentioned above:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    featureList=[feat['date1'], feat['date2'], feat['date3'], feat['date4']]
    idx = layer.fieldNameIndex( 'maxDate' )
    layer.startEditing()

    try:
        maxDate=max(x for x in featureList if x !=qgis.core.NULL)
        feat[idx]=maxDate
        layer.updateFeature(feat)
        layer.commitChanges()
    except ValueError:
        feat[idx]=feat['last_date']
        layer.updateFeature(feat)
        layer.commitChanges()

print 'Done'
```

**EDIT:** Code adjusted to ignore null values, taking instead highest date found. If all the dates are null, then the value from 'list_date' is returned.

Example with sample data:

[image]

Comment: Thanks 15Step, that works perfectly! Its working out the iteration steps that had me stumped.

Comment: Great! :) It would be nice if you could accept my answer (the green arrow)

Comment: sorry - forgot that bit! Done